# I need to create access to kuberentes-dashboard without any token and kuberentes-dashboard need to be open via vpn with complete read access

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I need to create access to kuberentes-dashboard without any token and kubernetes-dashboard access need to be open via vpn and complete user need to be have fullread access

Cluster is in aws eks

Please suggest me how i can achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@RajuK
You can restrict Access from VPN only using allowed ips annotations in ingress object of k8s dashboard.